# RedHat Linux/MySql server password issue

Tags: mysql, linux, database

I stuck getting started with MySQL server on Red Linux with a password issue.

I run.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-143 ~]$ sudo mysql_secure_installation 

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm not soo sure which password should be going in here. Any ideas?

Comment: try doing `sudo su root` first

Comment: I get the same issue when using `sudo su root`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I don't see how MySQL doesn't relate to development. We even have a MySQL tag and mind you my issue was not related to Linux at all but a new feature in MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhmm, got it. MySQL v5.7 generates a temporary password that get written to the log file on installation.

```
$sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Should do the trick.